# Reading POJO from Request Header Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Am trying to parse an object sent in the Request Header from client side to my spring boot server side.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/verify")
public ResponseEntity<genericResponse>   verifyToken(@RequestHeader("Authorization") Authorization header) {
    System.out.println(header.getAccess() + " - " + header.getTimeStamp() + " - ");
}
```

but I keep getting this error

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.bus.api.dto.Requests.Authorization'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.bus.api.dto.Requests.Authorization': no matching editors or conversion strategy found","path":"/v1/clients/verify"

So I tried to build my own converter in a way. Below are my Authorization POJO and AuthorizationEditor Converter

```
public class Authorization {

    private String token;

    private String timeStamp;

    private String access;
    // ... setters and getters are removed for brevity
}
```

The Editor

```
public class AuthorizationEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {


@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    System.out.println(text);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text);

        Authorization authorization = new Authorization();
        authorization.setAccess(obj.getString("token"));
        authorization.setTimeStamp(obj.getString("timeStamp"));
        authorization.setAccess(obj.getString("access"));
       setValue(authorization);
    }
}
```

The `prinln` gives me text [Object Object] and then gives an error

> A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

My client side request through ajax

```
function Auth() {
    if (token != null && profile != null) {

        var HEADER = {
            token: token,
            timeStamp: new Date().getTime(),
            access: profile
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(HEADER));
        /**
        * This request would first request a token from the Auth0 Server
        * The token is returned and that token is used to access API resource 
        */
        network.call(constants.VERIFY_URL, constants.TYPE_GET, {}, JSON.stringify(HEADER).trim());
        // window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
    } else {
        webAuth.authorize();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the format of Authorization header which is sent? do you have a sample? I believe it is a String not an object

Comment: @pvpkiran I have updated the question check the last part of the question

Comment: I think you should verify whether this is the correct way to send the Authorization header. Is the 4th parameter really sent as string in the header or does network.call expect something else there?